Total Divergence in TRPO
I have a problem understanding the following part of the TRPO paper by Schulman et. al. I don't see the reasoning of replacing $\alpha$ by total divergence an dhow the last paragrap allows us to use total divergence. What does "appropriate marginals" mean here? I feel like I don't get the last paragraph at all.
Thank you for your help!

